# Regex Pattern to Validate Text Input With Max Value and Max Decimal Place

Tags: c#, regex, html

I need to create a pattern for a "text" type input to only allow a number from 0 to a specific max value and at the same time and validate to a specific number of decimal places.

Quick example:
Max Value = 300.86
Max Decimal Places = 3

Valid inputs:
0
1
300
300.86
300.85
300.850
300.851
.2
0.3333

Invalid inputs:
-1
301
300.87
300.861
1,30.2
1,.0
,.1

Currently I only know how to validate number of decimal places using this pattern:
    ^[,0-9]*(.\d{1,{0}})?$

Note:
I can't use type=number because I can't use any pattern with that :(

please help

Comment: Regex isn't such a great tool for determining how large a number is.  Could you just check the max limit using .NET code and then also apply your decimal place validator?  This seems cleaner to me than a regex for everything.

Comment: @ClasG sorry I missed that. It is not valid. I just wanted to show that numbers with comma are accepted sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this, is what you're after:

```
^(300(?:\.(?:[0-7]\d{0,2}|8(?:[0-5]\d?|60?)?))?|[0-2]?\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,3})?)$
```

[See it here at REGEX STORM](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(300(%3f%3a%5c.(%3f%3a%5b0-7%5d%5cd%7b0%2c2%7d%7c8(%3f%3a%5b0-5%5d%5cd%3f%7c60%3f)%3f))%3f%7c%5b0-2%5d%3f%5cd%7b0%2c2%7d(%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%7b0%2c3%7d)%3f)%5cr&i=Valid+inputs%3a%0d%0a0%0d%0a1%0d%0a300%0d%0a300.86%0d%0a300.85%0d%0a300.850%0d%0a300.851%0d%0a1%2c200.2%0d%0a.2%0d%0a0.3333%0d%0a%0d%0aInvalid+inputs%3a%0d%0a-1%0d%0a301%0d%0a300.87%0d%0a300.861%0d%0a1%2c30.2%0d%0a1%2c.0%0d%0a%2c.1&o=m).

(Had to tweak it there, to end in `\r`, because REGEX STORM wouldn't match `$` with end of line even though multi-line was selected???)

**Explanation**

It has two parts. The latter `[0-2]?\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,3})?` test for numbers below 300. It optionally starts with `0`, `1` or `2` (`[0-2]?`). Then any two digits can follow (`\d{0,2}`). Then, optionally, it's followed by a `.` which, if present, can be followed by up to three digits (decimals) (`(?:\.\d{0,3})?`).

The first part - `300(?:\.(?:[0-7]\d{0,2}|8(?:[0-5]\d?|60?)?))?` - test for when the integer part is exactly 300. It may then optionally be followed by a decimal point, and one out of three cases:

- `[0-7]\d{0,2}` a digit in the range `0` to `7`, followed by up to two digits
- `8(?:[0-5]\d*|60*)?` an `8` followed by a digit in the range `0` to `5`, optionally followed by a digit (The `[0-5]\d?` alternation).
- or the number 86 and an optionall `0` (the `60?` alternation)

These parts are in a capturing group separated by an alternation - `|`. The whole expression must be at the start of the string (`^`) (or *line* with multi-line flag) and at the end of the same (`$`).

**Edit**

Done some tweaking 'cause some numbers wrongly failed.

**Edit 2**

Completely missed "the maximum number of decimals" part. Fixed. (Fooled by the "valid" example `0.3333`)

Comment: FYI: The `$` in multiline mode only matches before `\n`, not before `\r\n`.

Comment: OK. Good to know. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @ClasG wow nice regex
it failed for numbers with comma but I will try if I can tweak it thanks

Comment: What do you mean "numbers with comma"?

Comment: for example if max value is 1350.567 then 1,350 should be valid

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about C# so I'll just have to assume that what I can do in Python, you can find some way to do in C#. I'll give you my suggestion in pseudocode (this is not meant to mirror Python).

```
maxValue = some number
nDecimals = some number
givenValue = text with some number to be tested

#split number on decimal; remove non-digit characters from each side
leftSideOfDecimal = Replace(pattern = '^(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.\d*)$', replacement = '\1', givenValue)
leftSideOfDecimal = Replace(',', '', leftSideOfDecimal)
rightSideOfDecimal = Replace('^(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.\d*)$', '\3', givenValue)
rightSideOfDecimal = Replace('\.','',rightSideOfDecimal)

leftSideOfDecimal = pass leftSideOfDecimal to function to change type from text to integer

if leftSideOfDecimal <= maxValue and numberOfCharacters(rightSideOfDecimal) == nDecimals:
    do whatever you want
```

Alternatively, if you have a function by which you can split strings on a given character (like a decimal or comma), then you just split the input on the decimal, clean up the first side as in the code, and then proceed with the last three lines of the code above. That way would save you from having to use a mildly complicated regex.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but if OP had the option to use code, OP would probably go with something like `if( (decimal.Parse(sVal)<=dLimit) && (sVal.Length-sVal.LastIndexOf('.')<=4) ...`

Comment: @Chad sorry I need the validation on client side :(